# How can I restore proper functioning of the charge port in a tablet after connecting an OTG adapter that did not work?

Tags: usb, charging, usb-on-the-go, lenovo

I wanted to connect a USB external mic to a Lenovo tablet (P11) with only one USB Type C port (charge port). It did not work because apparently the tablet does not support OTG protocol.
It shouldn't be a big issue, except that now the tablet thinks the charger is connected all the time, but loose, or badly connected, and it's continually notifying to adjust the connection.
The battery icon shows as charging all the time, even though the charging port is empty.

Any idea how to solve this, and why it may have happened??

Thank you for your help!

Comment: I would be surprised if your tablet would not support OTG. I would power off the tablet and wait some minutes before switching it on again. If that doesn't help inspect the USB port carefully. May be the USB mic plug was defect and has caused damage also on the tablet port. –

Answer (score 0):

1. Go to Settings - About phone - Build number.
2. Tap build number 7x, Developer options will turn on.
3. Go back up to Settings.
4. Go into System, and find Developer options.
5. Once in there, scroll down until you find the USB default. There you can change it.

Comment: What should the OP change it to?